# error command failed to execute ... npm install

Tags: npm, phoenix-framework

I followed http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/installation to install Phoenix on a current Debian system but can't get it to work. When I want to create a new Phoenix application I get the following error:

```
abc@xyz:~$ mix phoenix.new test10
* creating test10/config/config.exs
[...]
* creating test10/web/views/page_view.ex

Fetch and install dependencies? [Yn] Y
* running npm install && node node_modules/brunch/bin/brunch build
* error command failed to execute, please run the following command 
again after installation: 
"npm install && node node_modules/brunch/bin/brunch build"

[...]
```

If I then run the `npm install` I get this:

```
abc@xyz:~/test10$ npm install
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /home/abc/test10/deps/phoenix
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /home/abc/test10/deps/phoenix_html
npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/home/abc/.npm-global/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.6
npm ERR! path /home/abc/test10/deps/phoenix
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, 
open '/home/abc/test10/deps/phoenix'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, 
open '/home/abc/test10/deps/phoenix'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/abc/test10/npm-debug.log
abc@xyz:~/test10$
```

What do I have to do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `mix deps.get` did the trick:

```
abc@xyz:~/test10$ mix deps.get
Could not find Hex, which is needed to build dependency :phoenix
Shall I install Hex? (if running non-interactively, use: "mix local.hex --force") [Yn] Y
* creating /home/abc/.mix/archives/hex-0.13.0
Running dependency resolution
Dependency resolution completed
  connection: 1.0.4
[...]
```